# Social media links appear broken in vcf format

Tags: reactjs, vcf-vcard

I am trying to create vcf file using [vCardJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcards-js) package in ReactJS but when I try to add my social media links, it appears broken in my IOS mobile device

```
vCard.socialUrls['facebook'] = 'https://twitter.com/kahvedenotlar';
vCard.socialUrls['linkedIn'] = 'https://...';
vCard.socialUrls['twitter'] = 'https://...';
vCard.socialUrls['flickr'] = 'https://...';
vCard.socialUrls['custom'] = 'https://www.usejanus.com';
```

[image: here is the phone view]

Comment: can you show the content of your .vcf file ?

Answer (score 4):

It's a vCardJS bug, which apparently has been [fixed](https://github.com/enesser/vCards-js/commit/574c9ea4b77ca95b85872fe0c1e5f97e1a67be98) in the latest code but not packed for distribution version yet (`v.2.10` at the time of writing).

As a temporary measure, you can fix it yourself in your code:

```js
let vCardString = v.getFormattedString();
vCardString = vCardString.replace(/SOCIALPROFILE;CHARSET=UTF-8;/gm, "SOCIALPROFILE;");
```